# Get shortest result first elasticsearch

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, wildcard

I work with elasticsearch with symfony2.
I have a database with music artists. 
When I try to search for example `"emine*"` with a wildcard, I got in the firsts results `"Eminence of Darkness"` or another's ones instead of `"Eminem"` which is closest to my query.

Please see this example 
[image]

What can I do to get `"Eminem"` in the first result?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard query by default uses [constant_score_auto](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) as rewrite parameter which gives
the same score for all matches.

For the example in the question probably you could sort the matched results by ***Artist.sort_name*** to get the desired result .

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the **Prefix Query** for boosting the results:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.1/query-dsl-prefix-query.html